# How is s3Client auto-wired in this project?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I'm writing a Spring application in which I want to use the AWS S3 client. All I need to do is generate signed URLs. The code that uses the S3 client is straightforward and I wrote it already, but I'm trying to figure out the proper way to instantiate it, as in, the Spring way.

I found [this project on GitHub called spring-boot-aws](https://github.com/briansjavablog/spring-boot-aws) that seems to do what I need. On `FileArchiveService.java` it has [these two lines](https://github.com/briansjavablog/spring-boot-aws/blob/c3dde2e9bd6871370606524d823ad356e04e2e5c/src/main/java/com/blog/samples/boot/service/FileArchiveService.java#L24-L25):

```
@Autowired
private AmazonS3Client s3Client;
```

When I add those lines to my project, I expectedly get this error:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'screenshotsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 's3Client'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I searched spring-boot-aws trying to figure out how is this bean provided and I cannot find it. I'm including the same dependency, `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-context:1.2.1.RELEASE` but that's not enough.

Any ideas how that project is doing it or how I should do it?

I tried coping the aws-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context/spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.xsd">
    <aws-context:context-credentials>
        <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="${accessKey:}" secret-key="${secretKey:}"/>
    </aws-context:context-credentials>
    <aws-context:context-resource-loader/>
</beans>
```

and a modified AwsResourceConfig.java:~

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/aws-config.xml")
public class AwsResourceConfig {

}
```

but I still get the same error.

Comment: I feel that the config file https://github.com/briansjavablog/spring-boot-aws/blob/master/src/main/resources/aws-config.xml and https://github.com/briansjavablog/spring-boot-aws/blob/master/src/main/java/com/blog/samples/boot/config/AwsResourceConfig.java together with the spring cloud aws deps expose an AmazoneS3Client bean

Comment: AwsResourceConfig.java seems to be for the Amazon database. I tried adding the other one to get the S3 client, but it didn't work. Same error. Also, I don't have any other XML file, so, I'm not sure whether I'm missing something else. I'm trying to stick to Java instead of XML.

Comment: I was referring to the `@ImportResource("classpath:/aws-config.xml")` in `AwsResourceConfig`. You can discard the RDS related annotation. You can try with XML first and then there are options to replace XML with for like [this](https://gist.github.com/arthurportas/7b6e5ffb413a507fb84c#file-configuration-java) one.